# Highcharts ng heatmap draw line instead of boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts

Highcharts ng heatmap draw line instead of boxes

```
    $scope.chartConfig = {
"chart": {
    "type": "heatmap"
},
"credits": {
    "enabled": false
},
"size": {
    "height": 1000
},
"title": {
    "text": ""
},
"xAxis": {
    "categories": ["23-02-2005", "24-02-2005", "27-02-2005", "28-02-2005", "01-03-2005", "02-03-2005"]
},
"yAxis": {
    "categories": ["Bond2Y", "Bond3Y"],
    "title": null
},

"series": [{
    "name": "Trades Data",
    "borderWidth": 1,
    "data": [
        [0, 0, 0.7642386249005615],
        [0, 1, 0.5010608923969173],
        [1, 0, 0.5009742082142428],
        [1, 1, 0.9114076033035807]
    ],
    "dataLabels": {
        "enabled": false,
        "color": "#000000"
    }
}]
```

}

[Angular Highcharts](http://jsfiddle.net/y9wjy0kz/9/)

When i place these config with JQuery Its works fi

[jQuery Highcharts](http://jsfiddle.net/7w6gq9sf/)

Is this is the highcharts-ng issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I checked your fiddle I had observed that you have not included the `heatmap.js` library.

Also, You need to move your `chart` and `colorAxis` inside the `options` block.

Check the below working fiddle link in which you can see the square blocks identical to your jQuery example.

**Working Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/y9wjy0kz/10/

Hope this helps!